# What is the best way to parse this request.data in drf, when the request is form-data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this form which sends an image along with some other data. I am using django-rest-framework in the back end. I need to take out couple of fields from this form input and do some operations and use the remaining fields to send to my `ModelSerializer` for posting the form data. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
class AreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = AreaMaster
        fields = '__all__'


class AreaMaster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    site = models.ForeignKey("SiteMaster")
    version = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    floor_map = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

> <QueryDict: {'areaName': ['Mall-24F'], 'devices': ['[\n  {\n
> "name": "device_001",\n    "coordinates": [\n      23,\n      56\n
> ],\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "device_002",\n    "coordinates": [\n
> 24,\n      57\n    ],\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "device_003",\n
> "coordinates": [\n      25,\n      58\n    ],\n  }\n]'], 'floorMap':
> [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1653650801973.png (image/png)>]}>

This is how request.data looks like.

What I have tried doing is

```
context = request.data
context["name"] = context.pop("areaName")[0]
context["floor_map"] = context.pop("floorMap")[0]
```

Basically I only want "name" and "floor_map" to be sent to `ModelSerializer`. I have read that request.data is immutable, but here it is mutable. I think I am missing something.

Comment: Can't you just send the whole `request.data` to the serializer?

Comment: the model I have needs only two fields, areaName and floorMap. The request.data contains more fields.

Comment: As long as you define the required fields in the serializer, it is okay to dump whatever you want into it. Serializer will only pick & validate the fields that you specified.

Comment: I also need to change the field name. From front end it comes in Camel Case, I need to convert it to snake case.

Comment: can you show you serializers, and model and some example to make your question easy to be understood

Comment: why don't you user validate or validate_field_name method inside serializer? @AbdulRahman.